# How to manage shape events with changing stroke width in JavaFX?

Tags: java, events, javafx, shapes

I'm writing an JavaFX application where i draw shapes such as Lines on a group, when i zoom into the group i dynamically change the stroke width of my lines depending on my zoom level. I need to trigger events on each line, with my initial scale the events are working just fine:

[Events working with intitial stroke width set to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck0kB.png)

Now when i zoom in and my stroke width is dynamically decreasing i'm not able to trigger events anymore. First the horizontal line events stop working and eventually i'm not able to trigger line events anymore after my stroke width decreases < 0.3.

[Events not working after zoom, stroke width 0.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtsKi.png)

Here is some of my code:

**Event:**

```
public EventHandler<MouseEvent> onShapeSelected() {
    return mouseEvent -> {
        if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            return;
        }
        SelectedShape.reset();
        SelectedShape.set((Shape) mouseEvent.getSource());
    };
}
```

**Adding of Events:**

```
private void addShapeEvents() {
    for (CitGeometry citGeometry : citFileHandler.getAllGeometries()) {
        Shape shape = (Shape) citGeometry;
        shape.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, mapEvents.onShapeSelected());
    }
}
```

**Zoom event:**

```
public final EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onMouseScrolledEventHandler() {
    return event -> {
        MapGroup group = Controller.getController().mapGroup;
        SplitPane splitPane = Controller.getController().leftSplitPane;
        MenuBar menuBar = Controller.getController().menuBar;
        double scale = group.getScaleY();
        double oldScale = scale;
        Scale.updateLevel(event.getDeltaY() < 0 ? 1 : 0);
        scale = Scale.getLevel().getScale();
        double f = (scale / oldScale) - 1;
        double leftSplitPaneWidth = splitPane.getWidth() + 7; // 7 = estimated width of separator of splitpane
        double dx = (event.getSceneX() - leftSplitPaneWidth - (group.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2 + group.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
        double dy = (event.getSceneY() - menuBar.getHeight() - (group.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2 + group.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));
        group.setScaleX(scale);
        group.setScaleY(scale);
        group.setPivot(f * dx, f * dy);
        event.consume();
    };
}
```

Does anyone has an idea why i can't trigger events on a certain zoom factor? Any suggestions or solutions for this kind of problem. My idea was to define some kind of area around a shape, and pick the nearest line on a pane click, that way the event wouldn't be triggered on the line directly, yet i was not able to implement my idea and was wondering if there is an easier way around this.

**Edit**

So i seem to have identified the Problem, but i don't know how to deal with this, if you use Intellij you can create a new JavaFX project and change the FXML and the Controller file:

**hello-view.fxml**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="248.0" prefWidth="335.0"      spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.2"
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
<padding>
    <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
</padding>
<Pane fx:id="mapPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <children>
        <StackPane fx:id="stackPane" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        </StackPane>
    </children>
</Pane>
</VBox>
```

**HelloApplication.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

**HelloController.java**

```
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class HelloController implements Initializable {
    private final Group mapGroup = new Group();
    @FXML
    private StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    @FXML
    public Pane mapPane;
    double mouseAnchorX, mouseAnchorY, translateAnchorX, translateAnchorY;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        addLines();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(mapGroup);
        mapPane.setOnScroll(onMouseScrolledEventHandler());
        mapPane.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler());
    }

    private void addLines() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            Line line = new Line(getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002), getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002),
                    getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002), getRandomDouble(5000000, 5000002)); // small coordinate range with big coordinates
            line.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, onShapeSelected());
            (line).setSmooth(true);
            mapGroup.getChildren().add(line);
        }
    }

    private double getRandomDouble(double rangeMin, double rangeMax) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * rand.nextDouble();
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onShapeSelected() {
        return mouseEvent -> {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Event triggered");
            ((Shape) mouseEvent.getSource()).setStroke(Color.RED);
        };
    }

    public void decreaseStrokeWidth(double val) {
        for (Node shape : mapGroup.getChildren()) {
            ((Shape) shape).setStrokeWidth(val);
        }
    }

    private EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler() {
        return event -> {
            if (event.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                if (!event.getPickResult().getIntersectedNode().getParent().equals(mapGroup)) {
                    for (Node shape : mapGroup.getChildren()) {
                        ((Shape) shape).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (event.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                mouseAnchorX = event.getSceneX();
                mouseAnchorY = event.getSceneY();
                translateAnchorX = mapGroup.getTranslateX();
                translateAnchorY = mapGroup.getTranslateY();
            }
        };
    }

    private EventHandler<ScrollEvent> onMouseScrolledEventHandler() {
        return event -> {
            double scale = mapGroup.getScaleY();
            double oldScale = scale;
            scale = event.getDeltaY() < 0 ? (scale / 1.1) : (scale * 1.1);
            double dx = (event.getSceneX() - (mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getWidth() / 2 + mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getMinX()));
            double dy = (event.getSceneY() - (mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getHeight() / 2 + mapGroup.getBoundsInParent().getMinY()));
            double f = (scale / oldScale) - 1;
            mapGroup.setScaleX(scale);
            mapGroup.setScaleY(scale);
            mapGroup.setTranslateX(mapGroup.getTranslateX() - f * dx);
            mapGroup.setTranslateY(mapGroup.getTranslateY() - f * dy);
            decreaseStrokeWidth(Math.max(1 / scale, 0.2)); // Change this parameter
            event.consume();
        };
    }
}
```

Now the issue only appears when i use big coordinates, like in our application we use UTM32 coordinates. Does anyone has an idea for an workaround and can explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: So while creating the mre i don't seem to reproduce this error, i will post the mre when i'm finally able to reproduce.

Comment: This is an important first step toward isolating the problem. If you get it sorted, you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188): exposing a design or coding error may help guide someone else.